# How to set up popup position's anchor for element in kendo column template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use kenod UI to create my Web UI. I have a column template like below

```js
var template = "<input id='details-button' type='image' src='images/detail_button.png' ng-click='showDetals(this.dataItem)'/>#: Contact #";
```

I want to popup a window every time I click the details button, and the popup's position should be at the bottom right of the button which I click. Here's what I do currently

```js
var popup = $("#detailsPopup");
popup.kendoPopup({
     anchor: "#details-button",
     origin: "bottom right",
});
```

But it doesn't work. Every time, the popup display at the bottom right of the button in the first row, not the bottom right of the button which I click.

Checking the generated html, all of the buttons' id are same(details-button). So the popup always display related to the first details-button.

**Updated:**

This is my changed solution, but still doesn't work.

```js
function popupDetails(item) {
            detailsGrid.kendoGrid({
                columns: ...,
                dataSource: item.Details
            });

            var anchor = "#details-button" + item.id;
            var popup = $("#details-popup");
            popupp.kendoPopup({
                anchor: anchor,
                origin: "bottom right",
            });
            
            popup.data("kendoPopup").open();
        }
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Is the template used more than once per page?

Comment: just used in one grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a static ID in a column template will naturally repeat it for each row, so this is not a viable option. You can concatenate the static ID part ("details-button") with the ID value of the Grid dataItem and in this way you will have truly unique detail button IDs.

```
template: "<input id='details-button#: MyGridItemID #' />"
```

Then, change the Kendo UI Popup initialization code to use the generated button ID.

**Update**

The Kendo UI Popup initialization statement cannot use a binding expression (`#: ... #`), because it is placed outside the Kendo UI column template. Use the `dataItem` object that is passed to the `showDetails` function and retrieve and concatenate `myId` again for the `anchor` setting.

**Update 2**

It appears that you are creating a new Kendo UI Popup instance from the same element over and over agan. I recommend you to [destroy](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/destroy) the old instance (which will also remove its DOM), then append a new `<div>` to the page and create a new Popup from it.

I am not sure about the `popupp` part, it may be a copy-paste error or you should be getting a JS error there.

**Update 3**

On a side note, a similar behavior can be achieved with a single Kendo UI Tooltip instance that is configured in the following way:

- the tooltip widget element is the Grid `table`
- there is an appropriate `filter` set, that points to the detail buttons, e.g. via a CSS class of theirs
- `showOn` is set to `"click"`
- use the `content` function to set the tooltip content, depending on the current target.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip

Comment: I use anchor: "detailss-button#: MyId#", there's an exception: unrecognized expression: details-button#: MyId#

Comment: thanks, how to reset the anchor? And, could I put the kendo ui popup initialization in show details method?

Comment: hi, thx for your replay, it works. But, is it a sensible solution? Every time I click the button should append an element to the dom tree, and after the popup closed, the element will be removed from dom tree. Is it will introduce performance issue?

Comment: The approach is OK from performance perspective. The alternative is to have one Popup for each row, which will require a lot more elements in the DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122711/discussion-between-allen4tech-and-dimodi).